# parsing a consecutive set of numbers from right until there is a leading 0 on the left

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I am writing an SQL query to parse a varchar column that contains Alphabets, integers, and special characters. There is a set of rules to parse the value. It starts with reading from the right side of the string.

The current problem that I am trying to solve is to do with extracting consecutive numbers from the right.
1.) If I find an integer first character from right, I should include that and any other integers to its left until there is a leading 0 or there is a non-integer value and put it in a new column. The leading 0 is excluded. So if there is 00 as a value then the expectation is to keep one 0 and get rid of the other.

2. If I find an integer second character from the right, I should be doing the same until I find a leading 0.

E.g.

```
for string "A12345" - 12345 expected
for string "A0123A" - 123 expected
for string "00123B" - 0123 expected
for string "12.123A" - 123 expected
```

So far I have tried to parse the string purely using regex and a simple SQL until I came across this issue of parsing consecutive characters with a condition. But I feel like there is a loop required to traverse which I don't believe is possible with a normal SQL.

Requesting for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

PLease check whether this satisfies your requirement

```
    with data as(select 'A12345' stuff from dual union all
    select 'A0123A' from dual union all
    select '00123B' from dual union all
    select '12.123A' from dual ),
    subset as (select Regexp_substr(case when stuff like '%.%' then substr(stuff,instr(stuff,'.')) else stuff end ,'\d+') stuff from data)
    select case when length(stuff)-length(ltrim(stuff,'0'))=1 then ltrim(stuff,'0')
             when length(stuff)-length(ltrim(stuff,'0')) > 1 then '0'||ltrim(stuff,'0') 
             else stuff end from subset
```